# what is the life cycle of FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie()?

Tags: c#, asp.net, lifecycle

I have a simple question related to the FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie() method.

In my Web.config file, it looks like

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Login" timeout="5" slidingExpiration="true" />
</authentication>
```

In my Login function, it looks like

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(entity.UserEmail, false);
```

As we can see, the cookie's expiration time is 5 minutes, and it sets to False for the SetAuthCookie method.

My question is, when user close their page and re-open and visit the same URL right away, is this user still authorized?

I am asking because when I am testing on my local machine, when I close the browser and re-visit right away, I am still logged in.

Any suggestion please?

Thanks a lot guys!

**PROBLEM SOLVED**

In order to make it work correctly, I have to close the browser complete. Although I thought I did close it complete, but I didn't. That is the cause of this problem.

Thank you all for the suggestions and helps.

Comment: When you close and re-visit, are you able to continue browsing as a logged-in user? i.e. click links, do stuff.

Comment: @JW Lim, I didn't check the function in this case. I have a partial view for the header. When user is not logged in, it displays Register link. When user is logged in, it displays Logout link. It is based on User.Identity.IsAuthenticated. When I re-visit the page, which is the index page, I can see the Logout link, which means the user is still logged in.

Comment: just because you have setup cookie.. thats why you are getting this.. as your login information is stored in it

Comment: @Ronak Bhatt But the cookie is set to false for the `CreatePersistentCookie` parameter. It shouldn't be stored across browser sessions. In this case I think that restarting the browser should count as a different session, right?

Comment: @user361022 Do you navigate back to the page or is the page stored as a 'previous tab' from the last browsing session? Sometimes the browser can show an outdated page that's been stored and will only reload when you navigate back/refresh the page

Comment: did you close the browser or just close the tab? Closing the tab will not clear session cookies.

Comment: exactly @KhanhTO is correct... have you completely closed browser??

Comment: @Ronak, oh, I guess I find out the cause of the problem... I am using FF for testing and there is always a tab opened for my web-based game... lol, Let me try again.